# Создание новой записи в Active Record в Yii2

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Здравствуйте.

Имеется запись в бд, к примеру:

```
id =>1;
имя => Вася;
фамилия => Пупкин.
```

Мы общаемся к ней и выводим значение в форме. В этой форме мы можем изменить только фамилию на Карандашев.

Есть ли встроенный метод, который примет эти значения

```
имя => Вася;
фамилия => Карандашев.
```

И сделает новую запись в бд?

Т.е. мы будем иметь в бд две запись.

```
id =>1; имя => Вася; фамилия => Пупкин.
id =>2; имя => Вася; фамилия => Карандашев.
```

Сделал с помощью load() и принимаю Get со страницы. На странице поля "имя" для изменения нет.

Выходит такая запись в БД:

```
id =>1; имя => Вася; фамилия => Пупкин.
id =>2; имя => null; фамилия => Карандашев.
```

Comment: Добрый день. Так в чём проблема-то? Покажите код модели и контроллера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создать новую модель:

```
$user = new User();
$user->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
$user->save();
```

Или можем создавать новую модель, на основании данных старой, и перезаписывать изменения, как в примере ниже:

```
$user = User::findOne(1);

$data = $user->attributes;

$new_user = new User();
$new_user->setAttributes($data);
$new_user->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
$new_user->save();
```